# d3.js charts framework modelling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While considering the performace Which model would be best for constructing the charts over d3.js? either closure type or constructor prototype model?

I have separate modules for each chart types(like bar,line,area chart) And one common module where i am  drawing the chart.

Here What is the advantage of using closure pattern over prototype pattern

Example common module:

//Closure Pattern

```
function chart() {
  var width = 720, // default width
      height = 80,
      scale,legends,axes; // default height

  function my() {
    // generate chart here, using `width` and `height`


  }

  my.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return my;
  };

  my.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return my;
  };

  return my;
}

var bar = new chart();
bar();
```

//Prototypr pattern:

```
var chart = function(){
 this.width =500;
 this.height = 500;
 this.initialize();
}
chart.prototype.initialize = function()
{
  //generate chart here
}
var bar = new chart();
```

Both looking similar. But which one is advantageous on considering

> performance,redraw

Comment: I would be interested to see what the performance impact is of calling simple functions in these two cases. Want to try creating a jsperf for it? http://jsperf.com/

Comment: this is helpful: http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html

Comment: here is a quick performance test: http://jsperf.com/javascript-prototype-vs-closure-performance

Answer (score 0):

Based on that jsperf test, it looks like they're all roughly the same, because it really depends on what your function does. But from the specific function implementation I chose, the prototype pattern **with variable hoisting** was faster on all the devices I tested (chrome, safari, mobile safari).

[image: http://jsperf.com/javascript-prototype-vs-closure-performance]

```
/**
 * List prototype.
 */

function List() {
  this.add = true;
  this.items = [
    { x: 10, y: 10 },
    { x: 20, y: 20 },
    { x: 30, y: 30 },
    { x: 40, y: 40 },
    { x: 50, y: 50 },
    { x: 60, y: 60 },
    { x: 70, y: 70 },
    { x: 80, y: 80 },
    { x: 90, y: 90 },
    { x: 100, y: 100 }
  ];
}

/**
 * Update without caching `items`.
 */

List.prototype.update1 = function(){
  if (this.add) {
    for (var i = 0, n = this.items.length; i < n; i++) {
      this.items[i].x += 5;
      this.items[i].y += 5;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0, n = this.items.length; i < n; i++) {
      this.items[i].x -= 5;
      this.items[i].y -= 5;
    }
  }

  this.add = !this.add;
};

/**
 * Update and cache `items`.
 */

List.prototype.update2 = function(){
  var items = this.items;

  if (this.add) {
    for (var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++) {
      items[i].x += 5;
      items[i].y += 5;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++) {
      items[i].x -= 5;
      items[i].y -= 5;
    }
  }

  this.add = !this.add;
};

/**
 * List closure.
 */

function closure() {
  var add = true;
  var items = [
    { x: 10, y: 10 },
    { x: 20, y: 20 },
    { x: 30, y: 30 },
    { x: 40, y: 40 },
    { x: 50, y: 50 },
    { x: 60, y: 60 },
    { x: 70, y: 70 },
    { x: 80, y: 80 },
    { x: 90, y: 90 },
    { x: 100, y: 100 }
  ];

  function list() {

  }

  list.update = function(){
    if (add) {
      for (var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++) {
        items[i].x += 5;
        items[i].y += 5;
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++) {
        items[i].x -= 5;
        items[i].y -= 5;
      }
    }

    add = !add;
  };

  return list;
}

var p = new List;
var c = closure();
var update = c.update;
```

http://jsperf.com/javascript-prototype-vs-closure-performance